# Supress message after running draw.pairwise.venn

Tags: r, venn-diagram

I am using the function `draw.pairwise.venn` from the package `VennDiagram` to create a markdown document with Rstudio. When I knit the document into `html` I see a similar message for every Venn diagram:

`(polygon[GRID.polygon.118], polygon[GRID.polygon.119], polygon[GRID.polygon.120], polygon[GRID.polygon.121], text[GRID.text.122], text[GRID.text.123], text[GRID.text.124], text[GRID.text.125], text[GRID.text.126])`

This does not go away if I set `message = FALSE`

How could I get only the Venn diagram in the final `html` without such message?

Answer (score 0):

Set chunk option `include = FALSE`. It preserves plot but discards any text outputs. See https://yihui.org/knitr/options/#text-output

Alternative chunk option: `results = FALSE`

Comment: include = FALSE removes the whole plot. result = FALSE does the trick